# Expanded child view position of RATreeView

Tags: ios, expandablelistview

I am working on a project in which i am using RATreeView. I have successfully
 implemented it. But my problem is when i expand cell my child cell is not showing properly at first time. After second click it shows perfectly.

Please visit [this](http://recordit.co/Znjk2jEXLl) for better idea.

Here is my code for custom tableview cell

```
func setup(title: String, icon: UIImage, level : Int,isChild:Bool) {
        self.title.text = title
        self.icon.image = icon

        if isChild{
            let left = 50.0 + 20.0 * CGFloat(level)

            let tFrame = self.title.frame
            let iFrame = self.icon.frame

            self.title.frame = CGRectMake(left, tFrame.origin.y, tFrame.width, tFrame.height)
            self.icon.frame = CGRectMake(left-25, iFrame.origin.y, iFrame.width, iFrame.height)


        }
    }
```

And here is code for each cell

```
func treeView(treeView: RATreeView, cellForItem item: AnyObject?) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = treeView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TreeCell") as! TreeTableViewCell
        let item = item as! ExpandableItems

        let level = treeView.levelForCell(cell)

        cell.setup(item.name, icon: item.icon!, level: level,isChild: item.isChildren)


        return cell
    }
```

Please help me. And i also want to change default selection color of cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i ll answer my owen question...may be it is useful to others.

I have added bit of code to my custom cell class as below

```
 var level = 0
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if level > 0 {
            let left = 40.0 + 20.0 * CGFloat(level)

            var iFrame = self.icon.frame
            var tFrame = self.title.frame

            iFrame.origin.x = left-25
            tFrame.origin.x = left

            self.title.frame = tFrame
            self.icon.frame = iFrame
        }
    }
```

and it worked for me